# Search Appliance - Multiple site search from sitesearch parameter

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am trying to use the google search appliance to search multiple URLs without listing them within the search query prefixed with `site:`.

Normally you would search a single URL in this way like this:

> http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=everyone&sitesearch=ebay.com

And we could search multiple URLs WITH them in the query string like this:

> http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=everyone+site%3Aebay.com+OR+site%3Abestbuy.com

What I want is something where we pull info from both URLs without it being listed in the query string. Something like this (but this doesn't work):

> http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=everyone&sitesearch=ebay.com+AND+bestbuy.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called site which refers to the collection.  In the collection configuration you can specify which url patterns you want to make up the search results.

See this [Link](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/admin_searchexp/ce_improving_search#h1segdata)

Comment: With a . you can add a AND operator to the site parameter to search within multiple collections if those two domains have separate collections. with a pipe | you can add a OR operator.